# Mui controlled Autocomplete both for multiple and single selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to code a Mui Controlled Autocomplete that can work both for multiple and single selection/s. Apparently this seems a simple task that you can accomplish just setting to true/false the multiple props of the Autocomplete component but actually when the multiple prop is set to false (i.e. a single selection), I start to get warnings and unwanted behaviours (i.e. the input is not displayed) as you can see in this code [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fancy-shadow-4x3ckc?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A22%2C10)

I am quite confused because in the [doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#country-select), there is no mention about different settings if you want single or multiple selection

Can someone suggest me how to fix my code so that it can work for both single and multiple selection?

I tried to set the isOptionEqualToValue props but I cannot get the country displayed when the multiple is set to false. Also, I keep to have warnings in the console

Comment: If multiple choices is enabled so the default value and value prop are expected to be of type array of strings. If multiple choices are false then the expected value is of type string. Make sure to provid appropriate value based of the current mode

Comment: @EliavLouski, I expected what you described but I cannot get the value I select in the autocomplete "input box". Furthermore, I get a warning that I do not get if i set the multiple to be true....

Comment: I've written a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are the key points when using MUI autocomplete with react-hook-form:

- define proper default values.
- use MUI autocomplete.isOptionEqualToValue prop.
- don't apply react-hook-form.onChange hook prop directly to the autocomplete component.

##### default values

When using react-hook-form with MUI autocomplete you should provide a proper default value when using the react-hook-form hook. react-hook-form can't know if you are going to use autocomplete with a single selection which means the `value` is typeof `string` or multiple selection then the `value` prop is typeof `string[]`.

```
const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    country: multiple ? ([] as string[]) : "",
    // even better
    country: multiple ? ([] as string[]) : options[0],

  },
});
```

##### isOptionEqualToValue

Because the MUI autocomplete relies on object reference equality but the `Control` component returns a copy of the option and not the option itself you should set `isOptionEqualToValue` to test if the options equal based on a unique property, for example:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label
```

##### adjust onChange

by default Control would pass onChange handler which takes the value `event.target.value`. well, we don't want this value so we should override it:

```
<Autocomplete
  {...field}
  onChange={(event: any, newValue: string | null) => {
    return field.onChange(newValue);
  }}
  ...
```

#### final result

you can change the `multiple` prop to make to the autocomplete single/multiple

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/inspiring-panka-ljkjyw?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A25%2C19)

code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

export default function CountrySelect({ multiple = true }) {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      country: multiple ? ([] as CountryType[]) : options[0],
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name={"country"}
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <Autocomplete
              {...field}
              onChange={(
                event: any,
                newValue: CountryType[] | CountryType | null
              ) => {
                return field.onChange(newValue);
              }}
              multiple={multiple}
              options={options}
              // getOptionLabel={(option) => options.label}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                option.label === value.label
              }
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label={"country"} />
              )}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
  );
}

interface CountryType {
  code: string;
  label: string;
  phone: string;
  suggested?: boolean;
}

// From https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlaskit-mk-2/raw/4ad0e56649c3e6c973e226b7efaeb28cb240ccb0/packages/core/select/src/data/countries.js
const options: readonly CountryType[] = [
  { code: "AD", label: "Andorra", phone: "376" },
  {
    code: "AE",
    label: "United Arab Emirates",
    phone: "971",
  },
  { code: "AF", label: "Afghanistan", phone: "93" },
  {
    code: "AG",
    label: "Antigua and Barbuda",
    phone: "1-268",
  },
  { code: "AI", label: "Anguilla", phone: "1-264" },
  { code: "AL", label: "Albania", phone: "355" },
  { code: "AM", label: "Armenia", phone: "374" },
  { code: "AO", label: "Angola", phone: "244" },
  { code: "AQ", label: "Antarctica", phone: "672" },
  { code: "AR", label: "Argentina", phone: "54" },
  { code: "AS", label: "American Samoa", phone: "1-684" },
  { code: "AT", label: "Austria", phone: "43" },
];
```

Comment: yes, in fact, i have noticed that I was making a mistake when passing the values, as I had not noticed that the array.filter() returns an array. Thank you :)